# Add the date from FormView to Gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a FormView where a row is "UserDate".  My Formview can insert,edit, and delete records, but the UserDate field is supposed to be retrieved as the current date and time.
default.aspx (HTML Markup)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="UserDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# DateTime.Now %>' />
```

When I run it, and Select "Insert" on the formsview, the date automatically populates.  However, when I add the record, it doesn't show in the gridview while every other column value does.
All other columns are user input like this though:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PO_IDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_ID") %>' />
```

The gridview resembles my sql database table po_table.

How do I implement the date to the gridview / database table?

Edit:
I'm assuming I do it here in my cs file?

```
protected void FormView2_PageIndexChanging(object sender, FormViewPageEventArgs e)
{

}
```

So far I tried:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="UserDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# DateTime.Now %>' />
```

which gives the date in the formview but doesn't transfer to the gridview when adding.
I've tried:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="UserDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval(DateTime.Now) %>' />
```

which gives an error.

My files:  (Class file)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PO_1_5_15
{
public partial class _Webform : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



    }

    protected void FormView2_PageIndexChanging(object sender, FormViewPageEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

HTML Markup

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Test_DatabaseConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [PO_ID], [PO_Title], [Date_Received], [Date_Completed], [Username], [PO_Note], [UserDate] FROM [PO_Table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="PO_AutoID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" EnableModelValidation="True">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            PO_AutoID:
            <asp:Label ID="PO_AutoIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PO_AutoID") %>' />
            <br />
            PO_ID:
            <asp:TextBox ID="PO_IDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_ID") %>' />
            <br />
            PO_Title:
            <asp:TextBox ID="PO_TitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_Title") %>' />
            <br />
            Date_Received:
            <asp:TextBox ID="Date_ReceivedTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Received") %>' />
            <br />
            Date_Completed:
            <asp:TextBox ID="Date_CompletedTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Completed") %>' />
            <br />
            Username:
            <asp:TextBox ID="UsernameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>' />
            <br />
            UserDate:
            <asp:TextBox ID="UserDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval(DateTime.Now) %>' />
            <br />
            PO_Note:
            <asp:TextBox ID="PO_NoteTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_Note") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
```

Comment: what does your binding code look like.. in the code behind..? sounds like a binding / you not rebinding the data to the datagrid view; issue after doing the insert / add.. please show .cs relevant code . if you are looking at Late Bound change the `<%# Bind("PO_ID") %>'` to use `EVAL` instead

Comment: Do you want the _same_ DateTime from the FormView to be displayed on the GridView? Or do you always want the current DateTime to display?

Comment: Yes, I want the same DateTime from the FormView to be displayed on the Gridview.

Comment: I apologize for forgetting about this question. As a tip: you can use the "@" symbol to direct comments at other users. The question asker receives notifications for every comment, other users do not. Using "@" makes sure they get a notification. Just type "@" followed by their username.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the *same* DateTime from the FormView to be displayed on the GridView, you will need to save that DateTime off somewhere. If you were to just simply use `DateTime.Now` in the GridView, it would always just display the current DateTime, not the time entered from the FormView.

My recommendation would be to have/add a column in your database table, as like a creation or update date. Then when you insert/update your database from the FormView, include the new DateTime in those SQL calls. Then just bind it like you are for your other columns in your GridView.